# Hibernate Search 6.2.1.Final [hsearch_agent] wrong column type [id]

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I’m trying to upgrade a service to use Hibernate search 6.2.1.Final, for some reason when my spring boot app starts up (against an empty database) it is encountering the error :

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id]  in
> table [hsearch_agent]; found [int8 (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting
> [char(36) (Types#CHAR)]

I’ve no doubt this is something stupid I have somehow done, but I cannot figure out what it is, presumably hibernate search is creating the hsearch_agent table, Postgres version is 12.16

Any pointers gladly accepted

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that on this particular service the hibernate search tables were created manually (via a flyway script) and therefore had to be migrated as per the helpful guide [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.2/migration/html_single/#indexes)